# How does $q\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}(pq)^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pq}}{2p}$ follow from a Taylor Expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Some notes I'm reading say that (note: $p=1-q$)

> $$q\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}(pq)^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pq}}{2p}$$

follows from a Taylor Expansion. I can't see this. I've tried re-writing it as

$$q\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}(pq)^n=q\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1!}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}(pq)^n,$$
which doesn't lead me anywhere (not even sure what I was expecting).

I can't see what function has been Taylor-expanded, nor around which point.

Comment: Presumably it is an expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$ about $x=0$ with $x$ replaced by $4pq$ in the end.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof) might help... (The coefficients in your sum are the Catalan numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting $x=pq$, this is just
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}x^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}.$$
This is the well known generating function for the Catalan numbers.

To prove it, start on the right. The $x^n$ coefficient of the RHS
is $(-1/2)b_{n+1}$ where $b_{n+1}$ is the $x^{n+1}$ coefficient of
$(1-4x)^{1/2}$. Using the binomial theorem,
$$b_{n+1}=(-4)^{n+1}\frac12\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{2n-1}2\right)\frac1{(n+1)!}
=-2^{n+1}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(n+1)!}=-2^{n+1}\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!(n+1)!}
=\frac{-2}{n+1}\binom{2n}n.$$
Here we used
$$(2n-1)!!=1\times3\times 5\cdots\times(2n-1)=\frac{(2n)!}
{2\times4\times\cdots\times(2n)}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}.$$